# jquery cookie plugin: saving positions of various elements with same class?

Tags: jquery, cookies, drag-and-drop

i have some drag and drop items, which are just draggable vertically within my body.

```
$("ul.bars li").draggable({ containment: "body"});
```

so the user can drag the items wherever he wants. now i wanna save the position of each element with the jquery cookie plugin.

when the page is reloaded i want to position each element again on the saved position.

so whenever the drag is stopped i save the cookie:

```
$("ul.bars li").draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var currentPos = $(this).position();
        $.cookie('position', currentPos.top );
    }
});
```

and when the page is reloaded (dom ready) i run through each element and query the last position saved in the cookie.

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.bars li").each(function() {
        var savedPosition = $.cookie('position');
        $(this).css({ top: savedPosition });        
    });
});
```

that's my basic idea, however i have no idea how i can save a seperate cookie for each element so the position can be distinguished. currently i overwrite the same cookie every time i drag an element.

how can i add some kind of a distinguishable variable to position each element at the same position where it was left before the page reload?
any creative idea how to solve that?

thank you

Comment: Could I ask what plugin your using for the cookie. Because I need to create something like this too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("ul.bars li").draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var currentPos = $(this).position();
        $.cookie('position' + $(this).index(), currentPos.top );
    }
});

$(function() {
    $("ul.bars li").each(function() {
        var savedPosition = $.cookie('position' + $(this).indeX());
        $(this).css({ top: savedPosition });        
    });
})
```

Comment: Looks promising. Just remember that you're round-tripping that cookie data on every request. Plus if you have a lot of draggable elements, you could exceed your maximum cookie size.

Comment: looks promising but doesn't work. always remembers just the position of the latest dragged element - not the position of each element.

Comment: @user239831: the `index()` method returns the index of the `li` element within it's parent. How you use it will depend on the layout of the HTML. If this isn't working, my guess is that the `li` elements have a parent that you haven't mentioned. Can you show some HTML?

Comment: thank you, it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Pghqv/5/ in this example there is no cookie class embedded.

Comment: thank you, i almost made it work. a bit buggy though, will find a solution.